# Docker composer project can't find/ping or connect to internal hostnames

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm running a docker project using compose (on Ubuntu 14 for what it's worth) and one of my containers can't find/see/ping/connect to one of my other containers.

The `worker` container can't ping or connect to the `db` container, and I can't - for the life of me - understand why.

This is my project:

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '2'

services:
  web:
    build: ./web
    depends_on:
      - db
    volumes:
      - ./web/:/app/src
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
  db:
    build: ./db
    volumes:
      - "./.data/db:/var/lib/mysql"
      - ./db/init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: redacted
      MYSQL_USER: redacted
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: redacted
  worker:
    build: ./worker
    volumes:
      - ./worker/:/app
    depends_on:
      - db
```

**worker/Dockerfile**

```
FROM php:5.6-alpine
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql

ADD redacted.php /app/redacted.php
CMD ["/app/redacted.php"]
```

**worker/redacted.php**

```
echo shell_exec('ping db -c 2');
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=db;dbname=redacted", "redacted", "redacted");
```

The output is:

```
worker_1  | ping: bad address 'db'
worker_1  | Warning: PDO::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Try again in /app/redacted.php on line 29
worker_1  | SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Try again
```

Comment: I had a similar situation, however it had to do not with containers, but with particular applications within the containers that could not resolve the host. Generally containers should be visible without links (from v2), but for those cases I had links had to be added. Having sad that I used an explicit network layout, that is defining the top-level `networks` and assigning the ones I need to each container. Try adding an explicit single network configuration (maybe they are on separate by default). But your case is the same as https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/ and should work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `link` in your `docker-compose.yml`. Use it instead of `depends_on` because it also fullfil `depends_on` purpose:

```
...
worker:
    build: ./worker
    volumes:
      - ./worker/:/app
    links:
      - db
```

More informations: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#/links

Comment: Doesn't `depends_on` serve the same purpose as `links` but also signify to docker-compose that one service is dependent on another?

Comment: Ah, I was incorrect, `links` does what `depends_on`, plus links the services. However, even after switching to using links, my service is still unable to access the database.

Comment: Try if you can access to it by `docker` name resolving instead of `compose` `links`. Exec into `worker` and try `ping <your_project_name>_db_1` (this should be the name of your container passed by `docker-compose` to Docker).